# How to add firefox to system PATH on Linux instance at Amazon Web Service?

Tags: linux, selenium, firefox, amazon-web-services, path

This is naive question but how does one add firefox to the system PATH on a Amazon Web Service Linux instance? I should clarify that I installed firefox to `/home/firefox` instead of `/usr/bin`. Thanks! I am currently getting the following error when I try to load the firefox webdriver (after importing `selenium`):

```
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 64, in __init__
    self.binary = capabilities.get("binary") or FirefoxBinary()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 47, in __init__
    self._start_cmd = self._get_firefox_start_cmd()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 163, in _get_firefox_start_cmd
    " Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to your `~/.profile`:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:/home/firefox"
```

Or to `~/.bashrc`, or `~/.bash_profile`, if the shell is Bash.

See [Shell initialization files](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_01.html)

Comment: This adds several unwanted Firefox executables to the PATH, like crashreporter and updater.
A cleaner way to do it is to add /opt/bin/ to the PATH, put Firefox files in /opt/firefox/ and symlink /opt/firefox/firefox in /opt/bin/: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248029/how-should-executables-installed-under-opt-be-added-to-the-path.